# Adjustment for binary classification with differing proportions

Tags: r, logistic, cross-validation, random-forest, bootstrap

My data had a different proportion of 1 (20%) and 0 (80%). I found [here](https://brennonborbon.wordpress.com/2018/04/29/classification-models-accuracy-isnt-everything-the-trade-off-between-sensitivity-versus-specificity/) that we can use upsampling to get a good sensitivity. The `caret` package in `R` allows upsampling. In the [link](https://brennonborbon.wordpress.com/2018/04/29/classification-models-accuracy-isnt-everything-the-trade-off-between-sensitivity-versus-specificity/), they tried a logistic regression (see model `sim_glm`) to do upsampling and specified `repeats = 2` to repeat the 10-fold cross-validation 2 times. I'm not sure how it works. Does it upsample observations with $Y=1$ and create a bootstrap sample "before" doing the logistic regression during each fold of cross-validation? Why do we need repeats here?

I also wonder how this would work for a random forest model. Will it create a bootstrapped upsample for every tree and then do a 10-fold cross-validation to choose the best ROC? Or it upsamples first and then creates bootstrap samples to feed the trees?